# comment on behalf of customer or user via Jira-ServiceDesk-API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-integration

Here we wanted to post comment on behalf of our customers.

We have our own Dashboard to take customer issues and that is connected with Jira ServiceDesk using ServiceDesk API.
We can create issues on behalf of user that gets to Jira Service Desk our support Team using.

But we are not able to post comment on behalf of customer.
When we commented that comment goes on our Support Teams Name as API is generated from that account.
Jira has rule that comment is posted on name of API owner.
we can not generate API key as it requires email id and password of user.
We tried but not able to set or generate password for customer using ServiceDeskAPI or REST API.
Here we wanted to post comment on behalf of our customers.

Comment: Congratulations. You've just described Jira working exactly as it's supposed to, and stopping one user from impersonating another user.

Comment: Here, we have developed dashboard with other features integrated. And using jira-service-desk-api to connect it with Jira Service Desk for customer requests. Is their another way to implement this?

Comment: Hi @DavidBakkers, the Jira Service Desk API does allow creation of resources like requests, on behalf of another user.

But for some reason, they do not offer the same campabilities on the request comments endpoint.

Comment: Hi @vishvaraj, I am also looking into this. a good thing that we have ChatGPT and Bing Chat, it can scour the web for us.
Right now, I haven't found a way, my current direction is to use a different API named 'Jira Cloud platform REST API'

Comment: @JustineM. It looks same as Rest API .

Comment: Hi @JustineM. I am well aware that ISSUES can be created on behalf of customers via the REST API, but since the OP's question was specifically about creating COMMENTS on behalf of customers, I gave the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2023, it is possible to add comments on behalf of other people (or in the case of Jira Service Management, customers) for Jira CLOUD and DATA CENTRE, but not for SERVER.

Your app will need to use OAuth 2.0 for user authentication, then make the requests to the appropriate REST API endpoints as that user, not as the app.

Refer to [JRASERVER-35124](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-35124) and [JRACLOUD-35124](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-35124) for more information.